# Given a number find the next higher number containing only certain digits

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to iterate in ascending order through numbers that only consist of digits 2, 3, 5 and 7. However the initial input number may contain other digits. But after the first iteration we will be dealing with strictly the digits 2, 3, 5 and 7 only.

#### Examples:

**Input**

```
 3257737
 3257777
 3257787
```

**Expected output**

```
 3257737 => 3257752 
 3257777 => 3272222
 3257787 => 3272222
```

These are 3 test cases on 3 separate lines. The output numbers could serve as input again to produce a series of increasing numbers.

My idea was to replace the last digit like this:

```
string generate_next_number(s){
    int len = s.length();
    if (s[len-1] < '2') {
        s[len-1] = '2';
    } else if (s[len-1] == '2') {
        s[len-1] = '3';
    } else if (s[len-1] < '5') {
        s[len-1] = '5';
    } else if (s[len-1] < '7'){
        s[len-1] = '7';
    } else {
        s[len-1] = '2';
        string s2 = generate_next_number(substr(s.length()-1));
        s = s2 + s[len-1];
    }
    return s;
}
```

I couldn't make this recursive code to work. It doesn't compile. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

---

I here add also a O(4^no_of_digits) code, although it is clear that this naive approach is not generic enough, as it is limited to a number of digits.

Here I have coded for a sample 10 digit number in python. For variable digits we might have to use recursion:

```py
    def get_next_number(num):
        t1  = 10
        t2  = 10*10
        t3  = 10*t2
        t4  = 10*t3
        t5  = 10*t4
        t6  = 10*t5
        t7  = 10*t6
        t8  = 10*t7
        t9  = 10*t8
        digits = [2,3,5,7]
        for i9 in digits:
            d9=i9*t9
            for i8 in digits:
                d8=i8*t8
                for i7 in digits:
                    d7=i7*t7
                    for i6 in digits:
                        d6=i6*t6
                        for i5 in digits:
                            d5=i5*t5
                            for i4 in digits:
                                d4=i4*t4
                                for i3 in digits:
                                    d3=i3*t3
                                    for i2 in digits:
                                        d2=i2*t2
                                        for i1 in digits:
                                            d1=i1*t1
                                            for i0 in digits:
                                                d0=i0
                                                n = d17+d16+d15+d14+d13+d12+d11+d10+d9+d8+d7+d6+d5+d4+d3+d2+d1+d0
                                                if n <= num:
                                                    continue
                                                return n
        # this 11-digit number scenario  will be encountered if num is 
        # the largest possible 10 digit number of this kind
        return 22222222222
```

Comment: What do you mean by trouble? please create a [mcve]. I think the best approach is to first solve this on paper, only then care about how to do it in c++

Comment: You want to find the next acceptable number "in one iteration", but you are considering a *recursive* solution? What do you actually want?

Comment: I can imagine "one iteration (in cases where digit != 9)" if only one digit in the input is not equal to any in the set of "allowed" digits. But what if input number has 2 or 3 such digits you will need to replace them all, and that can't be done in one iteration.  So maybe your question is not precise enough.

Comment: @Beta By one iteratiion, I mean Θ(1), it need not be O(1). On average recursion will go zero steps but in worst case you may have to update len(s)-1 digits. Isn't it ?

Comment: you write "we are given any other random number **not** contaning 2,3,5 and 7" but your example input does contain only those digits

Comment: if input does contain only `2`,`3`,`5`,`7`, then it is about incrementing a number in base 4. Its just about realizing that the digits are just symbols `2` is for `0`, `3` is `1`, `5` is `2` and `7` is `3`. Once you got that its just `++x`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number . I am not sure I get it but what you suggest seem very interesting for sure. Can you help me with the code? I am open to use different algos for first iteration and successive iterations if that is the most efficient way. I just want to make sure I am going it for best possible time complexity ie  Θ(1) for one iteration but  O(len(s)) in worst case for the full numer.. ie but overall time complexity should be Θ(iterations) not  Θ(len(s)*iterations) ..

Comment: You need to examine each digit, so the complexity is at least the number of digits.

Comment: please. Don't put complexity above everything else. The problem statement is even clear yet. You say "given any other random number not contaning 2,3,5 and 7" ie input is numbers **not** containing digits `2`,`3`,`5` or `7`, but in your examples all input do contain only those digits. What is it really ?

Comment: in a comment on the answer there is a thrid variant. There you say that input can be numbers with any digits. Please clarify

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: I propose to stop handling this question: the question is not clear and the author clearly expects quite too much from volunteers like us "if you can complete your code to something that I can run and test", that says enough, I would say.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number With brute force I can give you a dozens of solutions. I am here only for complexity.

Comment: @Dominique If you still have doubts please look at the examples. Question is very clear. You have to read it patiently.

Comment: @Jaspritbumrah complexity is completely irrelevant when it is not clear what exactly is the problem to be solved. You still didnt reply to my question: What exactly is the input? Is it numbers with any digits ? Numbers with only digits  2,3,5,7? Or numbers with digits not 2,3,5,7?

Comment: fwiw, if others dont understand the question then insisting that it would be very clear isnt helping us to understand. I have read it several times partiently and I still dont get how it fits that you say input has no digits 2,3,5,7 but all exampls have only those digits

Comment: @AdrianMole did you look at the examples? Please ask with exact question on what you didnt understant in the examples before flagging the question.

Comment: I repeat: You write "And also if we are given any other random number not contaning 2,3,5 and 7" but all examples have those digits. It might be a small typo, but such details matter.

Comment: "who dont have patience to read full question" ?!? now you are getting annoying. I am out

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Did you look at the third example ? 3257787 .. Did you notice 8 there ?

Comment: So, what would be your starting number (2357?) and what would be the end/limit? Iterating (or even interating) ***all numbers*** would take quite some time.

Comment: I admit I didnt see the 8, I am soo sorry for that. really. But 3257787  does contain 2 it does contain 5 and it does contain 7, so I still dont understand what you say

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Look at third example it will be clear why I say "And also if we are given any other random number not contaning 2,3,5 and "

Comment: I think you mean "random number containing also digits other than 2,3,5". Most of us are non native speakers, thats no issue, but I asked you for clarification so many times...

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. that's what I said at the beginning itself it we have to update every digit complxity will be O(no_of_digits) but since we will do series of iterations after starting from an intial seem even thoguh for few cases we have to update multiple digits but for most case we would have to undate  only one digit hence  complexity pe iteration will be Θ(1) on amortised basis, but it need not be O(1).

Comment: And why is `3257755` missing from the first line of your example?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I think its the same thing you are rephrasing, I have never mentioned the word "strictly". In that case instead of " containing also digits not containing" I would have written "containing strictly digits not containing"

Comment: @AdrianMole Sorry My bad.  corrected it. Had you questioned it earlier I guess we would not have got into all this confusion.

Comment: no its not the same thing. "we are given any other random number not contaning 2,3,5 and 7" An example for that is `468`.   `3257787` does contain 2,3 and 5. Anyhow I am not here to split hairs, though for you it seems to be about insisting who is right, and I dont see how this helps to improve the question

Comment: @AdrianMole starting number is the first number of the line in each of three examples. It would continue as long as the user wants, obviously thats not infinity. I omitted mentining it as it doesnt hamper codes logic. But if thats what's causing confusion lets assume you are asked to do N iterations for each test case.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  `468` would be "strictly" not containing 2,3,5,7 not optionally not contaning 2,3,5,7. Anyways now that confusion is done hope you can update.

Comment: what i said. You may be right, but that does change the fact that I still not sure what the input is. I suppose it is just random numbers (with no condition on their digits whatsoever), but I am not sure about that.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I thought the word "also" is enough to mean not  "strictly" or else I would have explicitly mentioned "not strictly"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Infact if nothing was mentioned , had I not even mentioned the word "also" , I bet still most people would assume it as "also" than "strictly"

Comment: there is no "optionally not containing a digit" or "strictly not containing a digit" a number either does contain the digit or it does not contain the digit

Comment: anyhow... once you do have a number that does contain only digits 2,3,5,7. You can reinterpret those digits as being `0,1,2,3` then you have numbers in base 4 and iterating though them is just a matter of incrementing them by 1.

Comment: AdrianMole and @463035818_is_not_a_number please vote for repoen if all the doubts are now clear. 463035818_is_not_a_number  check that line I rephrased it. If you want me to make any more edits let me know.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Lets walk though one iteration of first test case. 3257737  reinterpreted will be {1023313}_b10 = {3321311101}_b4, now increment will be {3321311102}_b4 = {1023314}_b10, now How do I reverse interpret it, it has digit 4 in it ?

Comment: simpler example `2` - interpret digits as base 4 -> `0` - increment -> `1` - replace digit with symbol -> `5`.  The last step is just a look up in the "basis" which can be represented as array `{ 2,3,5,7}`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number see if I interpret 4 as zero I will have to update the earlier digit(s) too. so we are back to square one. We get no benefit transforming base . We could do the same in base 10 also.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number square one is I have a brute force traversing all digits all the time.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number on stackoverflow we hope to get better solutions that the naive brute force which we can do anytime.

Comment: look, in your question there is actually no question. Only a fragment of some code and you say that it isnt working. Rather than focusing on complexity / and getting the best / the fastest so much, you must first understand the problem and get something that is correct. Anything is better and faster than nothing.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number What is currect ? O(4^no_of_digits) is also correct so is O(no_of_digits) but both would score me zero. So for me brute force is as good as not attempting the question in exam at all.

Comment: what exam? what score? No clue what you are talking about.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number In fact in real data that I have  O(4^no_of_digits) would take ages to run and O(no_of_digits) might take hours. So we cant even test it. Anyways for stackoverflow I am not going into dataset and all. To cut long story short base transformation was useful if incrementing could avoid having to change earlier digits like it happens in native decimal system.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number On top of that I have numbers which are 100s of digits long(which dont fit in 128 bits integer data types) , so converting it to a different base is a bigger pain than handling them as simple strings. Anyways lets keep dataset,exam etc aside for stackoverflow and focus on brainstorming for a better ie more time efficient approach. Let us know if you find any. Dont close this question or else you would find no way to let me know even if you find any later.

Comment: not clear how you arrive at `O(4^no_of_digits)`. Incrementing a number by 1 is less than `O(number of digits)` on average in any base

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number updated the question with a `O(4^no_of_digits)` brute force as well to satisfy your demand.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number For our cases ie your and mine earlier case are both O(no_of_digits). your case would be O(no_of_digits)+O(cost_of_base_conversion_100s_of_digit_long_nos)

Answer (score 1):

The recursive idea is fine, but some compile-level issues:

- The parameter needs a type declaration `string s`
- `substr` is not a defined function and you would need also to provide the *starting* index from where the substring should be taken. Use `s.substr(0, s.length()-1)`

And then there is a logical error too. The base case for stopping the recursion is missing. You could define the base case for when `len` is 0. Here is the corrected code:

```
string generate_next_number2(string s) { // Type was missing
    int len = s.length();
    if (len == 0) {   // Added base case
        return "2";  
    } else if (s[len-1] < '2') {
        s[len-1] = '2';
    } else if (s[len-1] == '2') {
        s[len-1] = '3';
    } else if (s[len-1] < '5') {
        s[len-1] = '5';
    } else if (s[len-1] < '7'){
        s[len-1] = '7';
    } else {
        s[len-1] = '2';
        string s2 = generate_next_number2(s.substr(0, s.length()-1)); // substr method
        s = s2 + s[len-1];
    }
    return s;
}
```

It is possible to make this code a bit more elegant:

```
string generate_next_number(string s) {
    static string mapdigit = "2235577222";
    if (s.length() == 0) return "2";
    char digit = s.back();
    char nextdigit = mapdigit[digit - '0'];
    s.pop_back();
    if (nextdigit < digit) s = generate_next_number(s);
    s.push_back(nextdigit);
    return s;
}
```

Or working with `int` input it could look like this -- but be aware of the range limit of `int`:

```
int generate_next_number(int num) {
    static int mapdigit[] = {2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2};
    int digit = num % 10;
    int nextdigit = mapdigit[digit];
    num /= 10;
    if (nextdigit < digit) num = generate_next_number(num);
    return num * 10 + nextdigit;
}
```